# how to setup a single install mediawiki in two languages?

Tags: wiki, mediawiki, multilingual

I would like to setup [mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki) in two languages without installing twice and setting them up as a [wiki family](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aWiki_family).  The [Language Selector](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aLanguageSelector) extension allows for UI to be switched, but it does not allow for multiple language content.  The aim is to have a corresponding pages in both languages (ex About Us in English, About Us in French) and a way to switch between them.  Not all pages will have their counter parts.

Answer (score 2):

I see two ways to do this - either instructional (e.g. "For English, use: [[en/Page Title|Page Title]] and for Spanish use: [[es/Título de la página|Título de la página]].

Or by using an extension to detect the language during a page save, edit, encoding on the wiki, and modifying the page to add the en/ or es/ to the page or page link. That would be best, I think.

Comment: Thank you.  Are there any extensions that can do this.  I would think this would be very common request.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know - I haven't written in Mediawiki code for quite a few years, now. Extensions aren't too hard to write - I suspect this would be a few days to a week of investigation and coding. There's an Enterprise Mediawiki code jam coming up in January in San Francisco. Although I'm not going, there might be a person or team who would help you with this.